# mvc 4 webgrid display

Tags: asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a select query result having repeated values in column1 and column2, whereas  column3 and column4 values vary for a given column1 and column2 value.

My select query result is as follows

```
  ab ab_ds a 4
  ab ab_ds b 6
  bc bc_ds d 8
  bc bc_ds a 8
```

How can I get a webgrid as below?

```
  ab ab_ds a 4 b 6  
  bc bc_ds d 8 a 8
```

Please suggest if I can do something in query or in the webgrid

Comment: It would help if you gave us the query that led you to the first result.

Answer (score 1):

If you use linq you can use the GroupBy() method.

Example based on a class where the comparing value is strings

```
    IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, ColumnClass>> groupBy = list.GroupBy(
    y => y.Column1 + " " + y.Column2);
```

This will give you an IEnumerable< IGrouping< string, YourClass > > which you then can use another linq query on:

```
    groupBy.Select(item => item.Aggregate(
    item.Key, (current, columnClass) => current + (
    " " + columnClass.Column3 + " " + columnClass.Column4))).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks.i have got correct no after grouping but i want to display this in view.is it possible to send groupBy to mvc view and iterate?

Comment: Yes you can use a foreach in your MVC View. Pass the list in through your model in that View

Answer (score 0):

This question is to general, so I will give a general answer that may help you.

I use the C5 generic collection library, that have the `MultiHashDictionary`, that is a general collection that you can load your results there and gets them the way you say.

The `MultiHashDictionary<K, V>` is like the `Dictionary<k,v>` but the key is not unique and you can group it with. It help me for results like yours.

Get the C5 library from http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/